# Как в sublime поставить символы между определеннных значений

Tags: регулярные-выражения, sublime-text

Как из одно списка прокси, вставить их в другой между "#" [старые прокси] ":::"

Пример:

1 список

```
5.9.56.112:3128 
173.249.24.52:8080 
192.121.232.96:80
78.85.163.31:8081
```

2 список

```
#173.249.24.52:8080:::login:pass
#192.121.232.96:80:::login:pass 
#78.85.163.31:8081:::login:pass
#5.9.56.112:3128:::login:pass
```

P.S. "Login" + "Pass" везде разные

Задача: взять или выделить и скопировать прокси из первого списка и поставить их между "#" ":::" во второй.

Смысл в том, что старые прокси умирают, я нахожу новые и мне нужно их разом заменить все.

Уже помогли составить регулярное выражение для очистки 2 списка.

Теперь второй список выглядит так:

```
#:::login:pass
#:::login:pass
#:::login:pass
#:::login:pass
```

Списки в разных файлах

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Шаблон: `([^\n\s]+)`, строка для замены `#\1:::`.

[*См. демо*](https://regex101.com/r/68s4qO/2) и поясняющий скрин:

[image: См. скриншот]

Comment: Эдуард, спасибо большое, я понял что задал не верные изначальные данные. Ваш вариант отлично работает для чистого списка прокси и оборачивает их в нужные мне теги, но после ":::" ещё идёт "логин":"пароль"

Я поправил изначальные данные, если есть возможность, подкорректируйте пожалуйста код под эти условия.

Comment: Пока что нашёл такой вариант. 1. Очищаю второй список через регулярное выражение "(?<=#).+?(?=:::)" 2.Выделяю в первом списке необходимое значение прокси черед "ctrl + l" 3. Делаю их множественным курсором "ctrl +shift + l" 4. Копирую и вставляю во второй список через множественное выделение "ctrl + shift + стрелочка вниз" 5. Вставляю. Мало ли кому-то поможет.

Comment: @SSH я уверен в том, что средствами одних только регулярных выражений это сделать не возможно. Но можно было бы написать скрипт на php, который справился бы с этой задачей. Но вопрос в том, насколько это целесообразно.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое, я значительно облегчил работу благодаря Вашим советам и помощи. Получается практически автоматически.

Comment: @SSH ну тогда можете отметить мой ответ как решение )

Comment: Вроде отметил, я здесь недавно, если нет, подскажите как отметить, лучше скрин.

Comment: @SSH нужно кликнуть по галке напротив моего ответа, чтобы она сменила цвет с серого на зелёный.

Comment: Нашёл, спасибо :)